# OR Operator as function switch

Tags: r, logical-operators

I feel a bit embarrassed to ask that rather simple question but I'm searching for a couple of hours now and can't get my head around.

I'm trying to build a switch for my function:

```
output <- "both"

if (output== "both" | "partone")
{cat("partone")}

if (output=="both" | "parttwo")
{cat("parttwo")}
```

This should produce `partone` and `parttwo`. Whereas`output <- "partone"` just `partone`.

How could this work?

Comment: `==` works with a single element.  You may need either `%in%` or `grepl` i.e. `if(any(output %in% c('both', 'partone')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we check the logical condition

```
output== "both" | "partone"
```

> Error in output == "both" | "partone" :    operations are possible
>   only for numeric, logical or complex types

As we need to check for either 'both' or 'partone', use the `%in%` on a `vector` of string elements

```
output %in% c('both', 'partone')
#[1] TRUE
```

Now, create a function for reusability

```
 f1 <- function(out, vec) {
         if(out %in% vec) cat(setdiff(vec, 'both'), '\n')
}
output <- 'both'
f1(output, c('both', 'partone'))
#partone 
f1(output, c('both', 'parttwo'))
#parttwo 

output <- 'partone'
f1(output, c('both', 'partone'))
#partone 
f1(output, c('both', 'parttwo'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this.

```
if (output %in% c("both","partone"))

{cat("partone")}

if (output %in% c("both","parttwo"))

{cat("parttwo")}
```

It will produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is incorrect:

> ```
> if (output== "both" | "partone")
> {cat("partone")}
> ```

You can write like this:

```
if (output == "both" || output == "partone")
{cat("partone")}
```

Or like this:

```
if (output %in% c("both", "partone"))
{cat("partone")}
```